# Android exception when popping backstack

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

This is a followup question to these questions:
[popBackStack() after saveInstanceState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474882/popbackstack-after-saveinstancestate)
[Application crashes in background, when popping a fragment from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962317/application-crashes-in-background-when-popping-a-fragment-from-stack)

I am creating an application which uses a service and is reacting to events which are created by the service. One of the events is called within a fragment and is popping from the backstack like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(stringTag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

When the app is in the foreground it works fine. When the app is in the background, I get an

> IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I have already tried overriding `onSaveInstanceState` with an empty method.

Why do I get this exception only when the app is in the background and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application crashes in background, when popping a fragment from stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962317/application-crashes-in-background-when-popping-a-fragment-from-stack)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
public abstract class PopActivity extends Activity {

        private boolean mVisible; 

       @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mVisible = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mVisible = false;
        }

        private void popFragment() {
            if (!mVisible) {
                return;
            }

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

when you implement the above code alone when you resume the app you will find yourself in a fragment that you actually want to be popped. You can use the following snipped to fix this issue:

```
public abstract class PopFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String KEY_IS_POPPED = "KEY_IS_POPPED";
    private boolean mPopped;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_POPPED, mPopped);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mPopped = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_POPPED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mPopped) {
            popFragment();
        }
    }

    protected void popFragment() {
        mPopped = true;
        // null check and interface check advised
        ((PopActivity) getActivity()).popFragment();
    }
}
```

[Original Author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962317/application-crashes-in-background-when-popping-a-fragment-from-stack)

Comment: but I don't use a navigation drawer.. I got a SlidingTabLayout

Comment: @JJAb only use the else part in that function then

Comment: but popping the backstack like I did doesn't call onBackPressed(). Also, the app is already in the background in that stage so I don't need to alert anything to the user. I just need the event to work while I'm in the background

Comment: There's a problem with the new solution since the onCreate method is not being called when the app gets  back from the background